# Split a string directly into array

Tags: arrays, awk, gawk

Suppose I want to pass a string to `awk` so that once I split it (on a pattern) the substrings become the indexes (not the values) of an associative array.

Like so:

```
$ awk -v s="A:B:F:G" 'BEGIN{ # easy, but can these steps be combined?
                            split(s,temp,":")  # temp[1]="A",temp[2]="B"...
                            for (e in temp) arr[temp[e]] #arr["A"], arr["B"]...
                            for (e in arr) print e 
                            }'
A
B
F
G
```

Is there a awkism or gawkism that would allow the string `s` to be directly split into its components with those components becoming the index entries in `arr`?

---

The reason is (bigger picture) is I want something like this (pseudo awk):

```
awk -v s="1,4,55" 'BEGIN{[arr to arr["1"],arr["5"],arr["55"]} $3 in arr {action}'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no better way to map separated substrings to array indices than:

```
split(str,tmp); for (i in tmp) arr[tmp[i]]
```

FWIW if you don't like that approach for doing what your final pseudo-code does:

```
awk -v s="1,4,55" 'BEGIN{split(s,tmp,/,/); for (i in tmp) arr[tmp[i]]} $3 in arr{action}'
```

then another way to get the same behavior is

```
awk -v s=",1,4,55," 'index(s,","$3","){action}'
```

Comment: I think that `split(str,tmp); for (i in tmp) arr[tmp[i]]` is probably the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: to avoid missing surroundig separator of *s* in second solution I propose this `awk -v s="A:B:C:G" 's ~ "(^|:)" $3 "(:|$)"{action}'`

Comment: @NeronLeVelu That turns it into a regexp comparison so then you need to worry about regexp metacharacters in the strings. The original code used a string comparison (`$3 in arr`) and so does the code I posted using `index()` so regexp metacharacters will just be treated literally.

Comment: ok, i forget to assume that part, you are pointing right about this possible issue

Answer (score 1):

Probably useless and unnecessarily complex but I'll open the game with `while`, `match` and `substr`:

```
$ awk -v s="A:B:F:G" '
BEGIN {
    while(match(s,/[^:]+/)) {
        a[substr(s,RSTART,RLENGTH)]
        s=substr(s,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    for(i in a)
        print i
}'
A
B
F
G
```

I'm eager to see (if there are) some useful solutions. I tried playing around with `asort`s and such.

Answer (score 1):

Other way kind `awkism`

> cat file

```
1 hi
2 hello
3 bonjour
4 hola
5 konichiwa
```

Run it,

```
awk 'NR==FNR{d[$1]; next}$1 in d' RS="," <(echo "1,2,4") RS="\n" file
```

you get,

```
1 hi
2 hello
4 hola
```